# Java FX text box not working

Tags: java, javafx

This program is suppose to store the values in the program to a when write is pressed. Then when read is pressed it will read and display the values. The results are supposed to be displayed in a text area. However, the buttons do not show up when I run the program. When I run it java begins to run on my computer but nothing comes up.

```
 package program;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class program extends Application {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

            // Text area
            TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
            textArea.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey; -fx-text-fill: blue; -fx-control-inner-background: grey");
            textArea.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));


            Button write = new Button("Write");
            write.setOnAction(e -> {
                // Create an output stream for file
                try(ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Exercise17_05.dat", true))) {
                    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
                    // Write to file
                    // 1. Write double
                    output.writeDouble(5.5);
                    // 2. Write int array object
                    output.writeObject(numbers);
                    // 3. Write date object
                    output.writeObject(new java.util.Date());
                    // 4. Write utf string
                    output.writeUTF("Exercise17_05.dat");

                } catch(IOException exception) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });



            Button read = new Button("Read");
            read.setOnAction(e -> {

                //Create an input stream for file
                try(ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Exercise17_05.dat"));){
                // Read from file
                   // 1. Read double
                 double doubleValue = input.readDouble();
                 textArea.appendText("Double value: " + doubleValue);
                 // 2. Read int array object
                 int[] newNumbers = (int[]) (input.readObject());
                 textArea.appendText("Integers: " + Arrays.toString(newNumbers));
                 // 3. Read date object
                 Date date = (java.util.Date) (input.readObject());
                 textArea.appendText("DateTime: " + date);
                 // 4. Read utf string
                 String fileName = input.readUTF();      
                textArea.appendText("File name: " + fileName);

                  } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException exception) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }});


            HBox hButtons = new HBox(read, write);
            VBox vProgram = new VBox(8);
            vProgram.getChildren().addAll(hButtons, textArea);

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vProgram));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Write and Read");
            primaryStage.show();


        }   
}
```

Comment: This works just fine for me. I copied and pasted the code and ran it, the buttons and text show up and work as expected.

Comment: The buttons are not showing up for me. Just the grey box with the title displayed.

Comment: Probably you have not saved or recompiled the latest version you have: there is nothing at all wrong in the code. Clean and rebuild the project (or whatever the equivalent is in your IDE).

Comment: I've updated eclipse and just downloaded netbeans as well and it wasn't working correctly on that either.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you get when you run it? As I said, I did nothing more than copy and paste your exact code into Eclipse, and when I run it I get exactly what I expect.

Answer (score 3):

add these two lines of code at the end of your code, to make your gui visible

```
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vProgram, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: @goblin You created one `TextField` and two `Button`'s, but you just not placed them anywhere.

Comment: @Denis Kokorin Since JavaFX 8 it is possible to pass Nodes to HBox and VBox as constructor params. This is what goblin is doing here. guleryuz answer is therefore already complete

Comment: The buttons don't seem to be showing up in the vProgram box. I have added the new code